# Clustering geographic data with additional variable in sensible way?

Tags: clustering

I have a very large dataset which includes data from specific geographic locations (e.g., lat, lon, air quality, for example). I would like to use a clustering algorithm to group these locations based on their similar third variable (air quality, in this example). However, I want to ensure that the clusters are sensible geographically. My first thought is to impose some sort of distance limitation between sites to be included in each cluster.

What clustering algorithms or techniques would be recommended? I'm a novice, so any hints would be greatly appreciated and I can then go into detail studying these algorithms independently. Thanks.